# Convert Integer in to decimal Perl

Tags: perl

I need to convert the following integers numbers

```
29900
17940
1
```

in to decimal format like

```
299.00
179.40
0.01
```

I tried already  Data/Types.pm but 
to_decimal(1, 2) 
return 1.00

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried? This really isn't something that needs an external module.

Comment: Judging from your quite advanced Perl stuff on github, you're in for one giant face palm. :)

Answer (score 12):

Perl does not have data types in the sense of integer, float or string. All you need to do is divide by 100. If you want an output with two decimals, use [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) to format it.

```
printf '%.02d', 29900 / 100;
```

Will output `299.00`. Note that [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) is like [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html), but with printing instead of returning.

You can read [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) to learn more about what *kinds of data* Perl has.

---

Under the hood at the XS and C layer, there are of course data types. You can learn about them in [perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Variables). But the whole point of a higher language is to abstract those things away. So if all you do is write Perl code, you never need to care that those exist or how they work.